# Getting "Frame window is not acessible" while calling custom DSL

Tags: angularjs, angular-scenario

I grabbed Angular Seed project and modified its scenario test. I'm trying a really simple test, so I believe it's something I'm missing. Here is the DSL and Scenario spec:

```js
angular.scenario.dsl('customDsl', function() {
  return function(selector) {
    return this.addFutureAction('customDsl', function ($window, $document, done) {
      done(null, selector + ' is ok!');
    });
  };
});

describe('my app', function() {
  it('should pass', function() {
    expect(customDsl('test')).toBe('test is ok!');
  });
});
```

When running the test it fails with the following message:

```
Frame window is not accessible.
```

I'm using **Windows 7** and running scenarios in **Chrome**. To run the tests, I start the server `node scripts\web-server.js`, then `scripts\e2e-test.bat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you need to move to a page of the application before you can run any scenarios.  Check out:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cG4CQI

Note that adding

```
browser().navigateTo('/')
```

solves the problem.  Take it out and you can replicate your error.